# How to create text-to-speech compatible header?

Tags: header-footer, viewers

In Adobe Professional I can add editable header and footer which will be skipped by the text-to-speech module. How can I achive this with latex?

Comment: Do you have an official link to this feature? It would help searching for a LaTeX implementation. Personally, I don't think it got implemented for LaTeX yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using technique called tagged pdf. Unfortunately, there is no support on higher level for it in LaTeX. [Patch](http://sarovar.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=945&group_id=106&atid=495) for pdftex exists, some examples of the usage are included in the file `f4.zip`, more information can be found in Ross Moore's [article](http://www.tug.org/tug2009/preprints/moore.pdf), he also talked about the tagged PDF at [last](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tex-mathml-for-tagged-pdf-the-next-frontier-in-mathematical-typesetting/) and [current](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/further-advances-toward-tagged-pdf-for-mathematics/) year Tug conference. But you need to recompile pdftex by yourself, these changes aren't included in pdftex from TeX live.

Better support is included in Context, [there](http://minimals.contextgarden.net/current/context/test/doc/context/tests/mkiv/tags/) are some examples. This also means, that support for the tagged PDF can be achieved with the luaTeX, but I don't know how.